# Custom ListView.builder -Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I would like to do **Custom ListView builder** as U see below, but I have a problem with index in Widget where I use it. **"Missing parameter type of index"**, could U tell me how to handle with it?

And how else could I make a Custom Widget that I could use in several places.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
class BuilderNews extends StatelessWidget {

final double height;
final ItemBuilder itemBuilder;
final ScrollPhysics physics;
final int itemcount;


BuilderNews({
  required this.height,
  required this.itemBuilder,
  required this.physics,
  required this.itemcount});

ApiService client = ApiService();
late final Article article;
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    height: height,
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future: client.getArticle(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var article = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView.builder(
                // scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
                physics: physics,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: itemcount,
                itemBuilder: itemBuilder);
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }));
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Define it like this, not `ItemBuilder`:

```
Widget Function(BuildContext, int) test = (context,index)=> Text('testing ItemBuilder');
.
.
.
.
ListView.builder(
              physics: physics,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: itemcount,
              itemBuilder:test
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you change itemBuilder's definition type from 'ItemBuilder' to 'IndexedWidgetBuilder'?

Because at the flutter 'scroll_view.dart' file, itemBuilder parameter type at ListView is 'IndexedWidgetBuilder'.

```
class BuilderNews extends StatelessWidget {

  final double height;
  final IndexedWidgetBuilder itemBuilder;
  final ScrollPhysics physics;
  final int itemcount;
...
```

<'scroll_view.dart' File>

```
  ListView.builder({
    Key key,
    Axis scrollDirection = Axis.vertical,
    bool reverse = false,
    ScrollController controller,
    bool primary,
    ScrollPhysics physics,
    bool shrinkWrap = false,
    EdgeInsetsGeometry padding,
    this.itemExtent,
    @required IndexedWidgetBuilder itemBuilder,
...
```

Comment: itemBuilder: (context,index) =>
        customListTile(article![index], context).  whats to do when the operator '[]' is not definded?

Comment: As I commented below article, it seems that article's type is not List type.